# Equal geographic coordinate grid intervals

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, grids-graticules

Is there a way of creating an equal geographic coordinate grid interval in QGIS print composer? I tried editing the interval and offset but it does not give equal interval like 121°14'0" then 121°14'15" and then 121°14'30" and so on.

Attached below is an image I layout with some details.

[image: example]

Comment: It'll help to use correct interval for 15" = 0.004166666666666. You're currently using the equivalent of 9".

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my query. Is there a computation for the different interval or list for different interval to be use?

Comment: It looks like you need to use decimal degrees, so if you want an interval in seconds divide by 3600 (# of secs in a degree).

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped.

Comment: Please feel free to write an answer. I'll upvote it!